# Matlab: Display Vectors side by side in a structure

Tags: matlab, structure

How can I display (in the variable viewer) 2 vectors in a STRUCTURE side-by-side like in a matrix?
It only shows up for me like this:

[image: Example]

EDIT:
This is how it should look:

This is what I want to achieve, but I only get this by converting from table to struct:

```
I.A(1:150,1)=[0];
I.B(1:150,1)=[0];
A=table(I.A,I.B)
B=table2struct(A)
```

Comment: Um, `[S.nsum, S.nmax]`?

Comment: I mean a STRUCTURE, not simply 2 vectors.

Comment: Well your struct has two fields.... Please elaborate on what you actually expect.

Comment: The variable viewer will never display two variables side by side. Each column has a meaning, so in the first one you have the variable name, in the second one the variable values, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable viewer only shows the contents of the fields "side by side" when it's a structure-array, which is constructed by the following commands:

```
a.a = 0;
a.b = 0;
b = repmat(a,[1 100]);
```

[image]